# matrix algebra (linear algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra

If we have the 2x6 matrix $\sigma$ (sorry do not know how to write this in neater way):

$\sigma$ = \begin{bmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6 \\
          6&3&1&2&4&5\end{bmatrix}

and we were asked to find $\sigma^2$, $\sigma^3$ and ... and then find their signatures. I am okay with the signatures part but I have no idea what this $\sigma^2$ mean..

for $\sigma^2$ my professor got the matrix \begin{bmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6 \\
5&1&6&3&2&4\end{bmatrix}

Please help! Tomorrow is my exam and I do not know what does this symbol mean!!

Comment: Squares are only defined for square matrices.  This looks like a permutation problem.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that this is not a $2\times 6$ matrix but a [permutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Definition_and_usage). That is,

$$\sigma = \left(\begin{array}{cccccc} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\ 6 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 5\end{array}\right)$$

is notation for the function $\sigma : \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\} \to \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ with

\begin{align*}
\sigma(1) &= 6\\
\sigma(2) &= 3\\
\sigma(3) &= 1\\
\sigma(4) &= 2\\
\sigma(5) &= 4\\
\sigma(6) &= 5.
\end{align*}

As such, the notation $\sigma^2$ means $\sigma\circ\sigma$. You can easily check that

\begin{align*}
\sigma^2(1) &= 5\\
\sigma^2(2) &= 1\\
\sigma^2(3) &= 6\\
\sigma^2(4) &= 3\\
\sigma^2(5) &= 2\\
\sigma^2(6) &= 4
\end{align*}

so to denote this function $\sigma^2 : \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\} \to \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ we would write

$$\sigma^2 = \left(\begin{array}{cccccc} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\ 5 & 1 & 6 & 3 & 2 & 4\end{array}\right).$$

Comment: This is definitely a permutation problem.